# The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. I have tried using the available answers but nothing worked

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting error

> "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()".

I have tried replacing and with '&' but still it didn't work.

```
roc_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['score','TP', 'FP','TN','FN'])

TP=0
FP=0
TN=0
FN=0

df_roc = pd.DataFrame([["score", "status"], [100, "accept"], [-80, "reject"]])

for score in range(-100,-80,5):
    for row in df_roc.iterrows():
        if (df_roc['score'] >= score) & (df_roc['status'] == 'reject'):
            TP=TP+1
        elif (df_roc['score'] >= score) & (df_roc['status'] == 'accept'):
            FP=FP+1
        elif (df_roc['score'] < score) & (df_roc['status'] == 'accept'):
            TN=TN+1
        elif (df_roc['score'] < score) & (df_roc['status'] == 'reject'):
            FN=FN+1
            
    dict = {'score':score, 'TP': TP, 'FP': FP, 'TN': TN,'FN':FN}    
    roc_table = roc_table.append(dict, ignore_index = True)
```

sample of df_roc:

| score | status |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | accept |
| -80 | reject |

Comment: Can you add a sample dataframe so that this is a fully functioning bit of code?

Comment: I have added the sample data frame in the original question

Comment: "nearby" and "fully functioning" are two different things.

Answer (score 3):

```
df_roc['score'] >= score
```

The error is telling you that this comparison makes no sense.

`df_roc['score']` is a column containing *many* values.  Some may be less than `score`, and others may be greater.

Since this code is inside a `for row in df_roc.iterrows()` loop, I think you intended to compare just the score from the *current row*, but that's not what you actually did.

Comment: I replaced "df_roc['score']" with "row['score']" in the code and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I replaced "df_roc['score']" with "row['score']" in the code and it worked. Thanks

```
(row['score'] >= score) & (row['status'] == 'reject')
```

Comment: `iterrows` returns index and row, I think you also need `for i, row in df_roc.iterrows():`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).